# Is there a neat workaround to the lack of foreign key identity columns in Entity Framework 3.5?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, foreign-keys

I'm having to downgrade a site from .NET 4 beta 2 to .NET 3.5.

The biggest hurdle is all the foreign key identity values I reference/lookup, as this isn't supported natively in EF 3.5.

Does anyone know of a reasonable work-around for this?

An example of what I mean is:

```
contacts.Where(contact => contact.TypeGuid == guid)
```

[TypeGuid] is a FK to [ContactTypes], so I get a [ContactType] object that I can access if I use `.Include("ContactType")`, but not the direct ID itself.

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to replace. It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do. There are *lots* of questions about FKs in EF 1 on this site; I presume you're doing something different?

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample query "just works" in EF 1 if you specify the ID property:

```
var someContact = Context.Contacts.Where(c => c.ContactType.Id == guid);
```

This is in LINQ to Entities.

In object space, you can refer to the EntityKey:

```
var someContact = contacts.Where(c => { var ek = c.ContactTypeReference.EntityKey;
                                        if (ek == null) return false;
                                        return ek.EntityKeyValues[0].Value.Equals(guid);
                                       });
```